# have div hover on top of input boxes using css

Tags: css, html, hover

I ave a div that popups up over my input boxes (javascrip auto complete). The div currently pops up behind the input boxes, how can I have this appear ontop?

screenshot of issue:

[image]

CSS Code is:

```
body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #000;
    }

    h3 {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;   
    }

    .suggestionsBox {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #000;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
        border: 2px solid #000; 
        color: #fff;
    }

    .suggestionList {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .suggestionList li {

        margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
        padding: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .suggestionList li:hover {
        background-color: #659CD8;
    }
```

HTML Code is:

```
    <div>
    <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
    </div>
```

Thanks as always for the help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `z-index` property on `.suggestionsBox`

```
.suggestionsBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border: 2px solid #000; 
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 999; <------ Here
}
```

Comment: Also you might want to use a bit of short hand to minimize the load as well as drop the vendor prefixes, as most modern browsers now use the un-prefixed version of border-radius.

.suggestionsBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 2px solid #000; 
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 999; <------ Here
}

Answer (score 1):

Set the `z-index` property.

```
.suggestionsBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border: 2px solid #000; 
    color: #fff;

    z-index: 100;
}
```